# How do I set my copy range when pasting from one workbook to another?

Tags: excel, vba

How do I set my copy range from cells B28 to Q33? I am trying to copy a specific range of cells from one workbook to the other. With my code below I keep copying most of the sheet.

```
Sub Button1_Click()

    Dim wsSource As Worksheet, wsTitle As Worksheet
    Set wsSource = Workbooks("New Initiative Template v1_30_2019.xlsm").Worksheets(2)
    Set wsTarget = Workbooks("PMO Automation.xlsm").Worksheets(2)

    Dim sourceTitle As Range
    Set sourceTitle = wsSource.Range(wsSource.Range("C30"), wsSource.Cells(Rows.Count, 30).End(xlUp))

    Dim sourcePjstatus As Range
    Set sourcePjstatus = wsSource.Range(wsSource.Range("Q1"), wsSource.Cells(Rows.Count, 33).End(xlUp))

    sourceTitle.Copy Destination:=wsTarget.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Offset(2)
    sourcePjstatus.Copy Destination:=wsTarget.Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Offset(2)

End Sub
```

Comment: How do `C30` and `Q1` relate to `B28` and `Q33`? Shouldn't `sourceTitle` be just `= wsSource.Range("C30")` and then `sourcePjstatus` be `= wsSource.Range("Q33")` then?

Answer (score 0):

```
Option Explicit

Sub Button1_Click()

    Dim wsSource As Worksheet, wsTarget As Worksheet
    Dim wb1 As String
    Dim wb2 As String
    Dim sourceTitle As Range
    Dim sourcePjstatus As Range

    wb1 = "New Initiative Template v1_30_2019.xlsm"
    wb2 = "PMO Automation.xlsm"

    Set wsSource = Workbooks(wb1).Worksheets(2)
    Set wsTarget = Workbooks(wb2).Worksheets(2)

    Debug.Print """sourceTitle"""
    Debug.Print vbTab; "Source Range:"
    Debug.Print vbTab; wsSource.Range(wsSource.Range("C30"), wsSource.Cells(Rows.Count, 30).End(xlUp)).Address
    Debug.Print vbTab; "Target Cell:    "
    Debug.Print vbTab; wsTarget.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Offset(2).Address
    Debug.Print
    Debug.Print """sourcePjstatus"""
    Debug.Print vbTab; "Source Range:"
    Debug.Print vbTab; wsSource.Range(wsSource.Range("Q1"), wsSource.Cells(Rows.Count, 33).End(xlUp)).Address
    Debug.Print vbTab; "Target Cell:    "
    Debug.Print vbTab; wsTarget.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Offset(2).Address
    Debug.Print

    'refers to the last cell in column AD: wsSource.Cells(Rows.Count, 30).End(xlUp)
    'correct? intended?
    Set sourceTitle = wsSource.Range(wsSource.Range("C30"), wsSource.Cells(Rows.Count, 30).End(xlUp))

    'refers to the last cell in column AG: wsSource.Cells(Rows.Count, 33).End(xlUp))
    'correct? intended?
    Set sourcePjstatus = wsSource.Range(wsSource.Range("Q1"), wsSource.Cells(Rows.Count, 33).End(xlUp))

    sourceTitle.Copy Destination:=wsTarget.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Offset(2)
    sourcePjstatus.Copy Destination:=wsTarget.Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Offset(2)

End Sub
```

Your code actually does work.
I estimate that you don't intend to copy the cells which you do address:

```
"sourceTitle"
    Source Range:
    $C$1:$AD$30
    Target Cell:
    $B$5
```

```
"sourcePjstatus"
    Source Range:
    $Q$1:$AG$1
    Target Cell:
    $B$5
```

The definition of the copy method is straight forward:

copyRange.Copy Destination:=destinationRange

```
Sub CopySample()
Dim copyRange as Range
Dim destinationRange as Range

set copyRange        = Workbooks("workbook1.xlsx").Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:D4")
set destinationRange = Workbooks("workbook2.xlsx").Sheets("Sheet2").Range("B8")

copyRange.Copy Destination:=destinationRange
End Sub
```

Below a screenshot of the result:

[image]